# How to list all of my bot guild names near the ids discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

How to list all of the guild ids and names instead of one?

```
@client.command()
async def guilds(ctx):
for guild in client.guilds:
    em=discord.Embed(title="GUILD IDS",description=f"{[guild.name + ' : '+ str(guild.id)]}")
  await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
@client.command()
async def commandname(ctx):
    listGuild = []
    for guild in client.guilds:
        listGuild.extend(f"{guild.name}:{guild.id}")
print(listGuild)
```

Comment: change the "guild.id,guild.name" to f"{guild.name} : {guild.id}" and that will be a bit better,thanks